# I'm having trouble adding items from a list to a listBox in Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I have a list box in the design and have a list that I'm attempting to load into a ListBox so that I can then select Items from that ListBox. I used the the code from the .Docs page on ListBox class and that doesn't seem to work. As I keep getting a CS1656 error on `ltbxCurrentRaceOrder.Items.Add`

```
int count = 0;
ltbxCurrentRaceOrder.BeginUpdate();
while (count != GlobalClass.allNames.Count)
{
    ltbxCurrentRaceOrder.Items.Add = GlobalClass.allNames[count];
    count = count + 1;
}
ltbxCurrentRaceOrder.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Did you mean `ltbxCurrentRaceOrder.Items.Add(GlobalClass.allNames[count]);`?

Answer (score 0):

`ltbxCurrentRaceOrder.Items.Add` is a function, yet you're using it as a property. Use it like this instead:

```
ltbxCurrentRaceOrder.Items.Add(GlobalClass.allNames[count]);
```